# Bag/Pouch for Zoom H6

Tags: field-recorder, bag, zoom-h6

I'm sure a lot of people bought the Zoom H6 as a handy recorder for some situations.

I just bought it too, and I'm wondering how to wear it, since I will use it with a boom and a pre. I want to keep it on my belt. (I will also attach it to my boom pole sometimes, but that's a different topic)

I've seen some Portabrace products that might fit, but that the natural purchase seems to be the Petrol PS 615 pouch, but it is designed for the H4n, so I would like to know if anyone used it with a H6 instead. Does it fit?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognized that the "Rode Stereo Videomic Pouch/Bag" fits almost perfectly (though a little loose) around the H6. So I use it as a compact stowing solution. The pouch cost me 16 bucs and is made from neoprene.
Because I needed a compact carry pouch for the H6 I just took one of those neoprene pouches along with a box cutter and cut away everything that would have to be accessible, superglued a plastic foil under the front and closed it up with velcro...
It takes some time and interest in handcrafting ;) but it works perfectly and appears to be a much better fit than the Portabrace thing that retails for almost a 100 bucs (but will be sturdier).
I hang that thing around my shoulder, waist or neck with the lanyard. (Which of course you could also do without the pouch as the H6 has two lanyard slots at the bottom). Keeping it on a belt may not be satisfying as you won't be able to see the display while recording.
With the pouch, if you strap it well, you'll be able to see the display while recording hands-free.
All that may sound a little whacky at first, but I find that sometimes it is quicker to DIY. Any way you want or need it…

Answer (score 1):

I do this rig for myself

I simply tie a camera strap to the Zoom H6 and hang it around my neck. The problem is that every time you need to put it on, you have to tie it up like a shoe lace and not quickly like some tether. You cannot use something like a tether or plastic or anything hard to attach the recorder with the strap, otherwise it will give handling noise while using any of the module mics (if you are using mics through XLR inputs then handling noise won't be a problem)

Now to stabilize the recorder I screw in the Manfrotto Pixi mini tripod. I let the three legs (fully extended) rest on my lower body, this helps in tilting up the recorder so that I can see the mixer.

Here you go! a full fledged location recording rig :)

Answer (score 0):

The Portabrace / Petrol bags are awesome and worth their money but I would suggest that you go look at a military surplus store, outdoor / adventure store or whatever you want to call them and take a look at the myriad of pouches and carry systems those places tend to have.

Chances are good you will find exactly what you need there with all kinds of different attachment and carry options to suit your style of work.

Last but not least prices on those things are usually unbeatable too.